# SSRS 2016 : Installation Issue Report Server WMI Provider error

Tags: reporting-services

Dears,

Have an installation SSRS 2016 on Windows 10 (64-bit) but encounter below exception when click Connect to sever instance in Reporting Services Configuration Manager. Anyone knows the reason and how to solve it ?

I follow this installation step and encounter issue on #11 Step 1.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/install-reporting-services-native-mode-report-server

Thanks !

Andy Wong

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.WMIProviderException: Report Server WMI Provider error